# Why does GCC optimize out assignments here?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, language-lawyer, c++17

I have a class `offset_ptr` that works like a pointer but stores the memory address it points to as offset to its own address `this`. Here is a version with everything removed that's not required to demonstrate the problem:

```
template <typename T>
struct offset_ptr {
  using offset_t = int64_t;
  static constexpr auto const NULLPTR_OFFSET =
      std::numeric_limits<offset_t>::max();

  offset_ptr(T const* p)
      : offset_{p == nullptr ? NULLPTR_OFFSET
                             : static_cast<offset_t>(
                                   reinterpret_cast<uint8_t const*>(p) -
                                   reinterpret_cast<uint8_t const*>(this))} {}

  T* get() {
    return 
        offset_ == NULLPTR_OFFSET
            ? nullptr
            : reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(this) + offset_);
  }

  offset_t offset_;
};
```

This code does not work with GCC `-O2` and `-O3`:

```
int* get() {
  offset_ptr<int> ptr = static_cast<int*>(malloc(sizeof(int)));
  auto p = ptr.get();
  *p = 110;  // WOW - please do not optimize me away :-(
  return p;
}
```

*(memory management and error checking intentionally omitted to keep it simple!)*

This is also visible in the generated assembly:
https://godbolt.org/z/PfZEJM

The assignment is just missing.

As shown in the Godbolt Compiler Explorer link above it works when

- the assigned value is used **directly** in the function itself
- the `offset_ptr` is located on the heap, not on the stack
- no `offset_ptr` is used at all

It works for:

- Clang (with and without optimizations)
- MSVC (Debug and Release mode)
- GCC (current as well as old versions) `-O0` and `-O1` (but **NOT** for `-O2` and `-O3`)

GCC and Clang Address and UB sanitizer builds do not indicate any problems (besides the leaked memory) when executed.

Can someone point out a section in the C++ standard document that says that there is UB in this code (which could be the reason for GCC aggressively optimizing out the assignment)? Or is it a bug in GCC?

Edit:
Removing the `nullptr` checks in `offset_ptr` helps (https://godbolt.org/z/5HjcLY). But I need those null-checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this work, if you use `reinterpret_cast` to `uintptr_t` instead of `uint8_t *`. This way you trade UB to implementation-defined behavior.

See: https://godbolt.org/z/rBTqYl

Answer (score 2):

[[expr.add]p5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#5):

> When two pointer expressions P and Q are subtracted, the type of the result is an implementation-defined signed integral type; [...]
>
> - If P and Q both evaluate to null pointer values, the result is 0.
> - Otherwise, if P and Q point to, respectively, elements `x[i]` and `x[j]` of the same array object `x`, the expression P - Q has the value `i-j`.
> - Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

The subtraction in the member initializer list falls back on the third point so you have UB.

It "works" if you remove the `nullptr` checks because gcc cannot prove that the first condition doesn't happen.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So there is no way to have a `offset_ptr` type? Or can the code above be fixed?

Comment: I don't think so, but then again I have no idea why you wouldn't just store the pointer directly.

Comment: Ok. It's useful when serializing data to a buffer. An `offset_ptr` like type (including data structures that use it, e.g. a custom vector or unique_ptr class) can be deserialized by just a cast when it stores the offset to the pointed to object in the serialized buffer.

Comment: Wouldn't the offset always be different because `this` is never the same?

Comment: When both, the pointer and the pointed to object, are copied to the buffer, the offset is fixed - regardless where the buffer will be located after being loaded (e.g. from file or over network). The distance between `this` and the pointed to value is constant when both values are in the "serialized" buffer. This would allow for memory mapped access without a real deserialization step.

Comment: Ah got it. But still, how do you know that there isn't some process' memory between `this` and `p` - that doesn't get written into the buffer?

Comment: @FelixGündling You can do that at serialization instead of "live" in memory.  Offset ptrs in memory are only really key when you are using an inter-process shared memory block, where the bits are interpreted in two different address spaces *at once*.